# binary encoding Little endian in python

Tags: python, go, endianness

I usually use golang for implementations and I need to implement a python project. I have the following instructions (Golang)

```
import "encoding/binary"
arBytes := make([]byte, 16)
    _, err := rand.Read(arBytes)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
a0 = binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(arBytes[0:8])
```

I need to write the python's version for these instructions but i do not found any way to create an array of little Endian from Uint64. Is there any available solution that can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent Python program would be as follows.

- Use [`secrets.token_bytes(16)`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_bytes) to generate 16 random bytes, like `rand.Read(arBytes)` would.
- Then use [`int.from_bytes(..., "little")`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) on that byte array to interpret the bytes as a little-endian integer. `from_bytes` defaults to unsigned values.

```
import secrets
b = secrets.token_bytes(16)
val = int.from_bytes(b[:8], "little")
```